# Define a unique global function when instantiating a class and pass data to it?

Tags: javascript

I'm working with an API that requires a global function for it's callback.

I define the callback within a class, that can be instantiated several times on the same page.

```
SubmitForm = function(el) {
    this.el = $(el);
};

SubmitForm.prototype.api = function(){
    grecaptcha.render(this.el,{
     'sitekey' : '6Lfk4SATAAAAAMsKUioOBFfgcLr_tERuvbsr3pun', 
     'callback': callbackFunction
   });
};
```

Where callbackFunncton references a function `window.callbackFunction`

How can I, for every instance of the class create a unique global callback function and also pass `this.el` into that function?

I'm thinking maybe something like naming the function a random number, but not sure if I can pass `this.el` into that function somehow.

```
SubmitForm = function(el) {
    this.el = $(el);
    this.rand = Math.random();
};

SubmitForm.prototype.api = function(){
    grecaptcha.render(this.el,{
     'sitekey' : '6Lfk4SATAAAAAMsKUioOBFfgcLr_tERuvbsr3pun', 
     'callback': callbackFunction
   });
};

window[this.rand] = function(this.el){
   ...
}
```

Comment: Nothing in your example gives the impression that the callback has to be global, and if it's Google Recaptcha, I'm sure it doesn't need to be. What makes you think it needs to be a global?

Answer (score 0):

you could create an object which holds all the functions like

```
window.myCallbackFunctions = new Object();
```

then add a static variable to your class where you count up the instances

```
SubmitForm.instanceCount
```

every new instance you assign a new callbackfunction

```
window.myCallbackFunctions[SubmitForm.instanceCount] = function(obj) {};
```

you can't "pass" directly the "this.el". This has to be done by the callback.

Comment: How would I reference this callback in grecaptcha.render, this must reference a global function?

Comment: @Himmators: *"How would I reference this callback in grecaptcha.render, this must reference a global function?"* I guarantee you it doesn't. Point to the documentation where you think it says it does, and I'll explain what you're misreading.

Comment: Like 'callback': window.myCallbackFunctions[SubmitForm.instanceCount]

Comment: but like @T.J.Crowder pointed out, I don't think it has to be a global function